# Json Array without passing array name?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String Array = b.getString("ITEM_EXTRA");
    String Tripname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Trip");

    try {
        JSONArray jO = new JSONArray(Array);

        for(int i=0;i<jO.length();i++) {
            JSONObject tripObject = jO.getJSONObject(i);

            String Trips = tripObject.getString("TripNO");
            JSONArray arrayJson = tripObject.getJSONArray("Trips");

            if(Trips.equals(Tripname)) {

            }
```

[JSON Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRuj.png)

I want to get the `Sfltlattitude` and `SfltLogitude`. In string `Tripname` I am passing the key `Trip1` from the other activity as the `TRIPNO` is not defined(the `TRIPNO`  can be any `trip2`.. and so on). In `arrayJson` I am getting the array of `TRIP1`, but I'm not able to get the `Sfltlattitude` or `SfltLogitude`.

Comment: What is `getString("Trip")` retrieving? I don't see it anywhere in the JSON. I also don't see `"ITEM_EXTRA"` anywhere. Please post all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`

```
if(Trips.equals(Tripname)) {}
```

to

```
 if(Trips.equalsIgnoreCase(Tripname)) {}
```